# How to use MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS?

Tags: laravel, email, gmail, lumen

Currently, I'm working on a feature that requires the application to send emails to customers/users.

Sending emails is already working, however, I want the sender's email to be hidden/replaced. I thought that the *MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS*
 in *.env* file is what I needed, but it didn't give me what I expected.

Here's a snippet from my .env file:

```
# illuminate/mail
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=steven@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=PASSWORD_HERE
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=admin@MyApp.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=MyApp
```

Should the user receive an email coming from my app, it should display "admin@MyApp.com" as the sender of the email.

+------+

Why is *MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS* not working?

How should I use it?

Am I wrong to think that it is the solution to my problem?

What should I do to achieve the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't replace sender with Google SMTP service.

Google rewrites the From and Reply-To headers in messages you send via it's SMTP service to values which relate to your gmail account.

GMail does allow [sending via different addresses or alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en) but this is for sending via the GMail web app.

Solution: If you own the domain you are supposedly sending from, use the [gmail for domains](https://gsuite.google.com/), and setup a "myapp@mydomain.com" account.

Answer (score -1):

In `config/mail.php`, please put your email address over there then you will get that mail from that email address

```
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'admin@MyApp.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Sure, but shouldn't env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS') retrieve the value in .env??