# Sendgrid [apikey] does not comply with RFC 2822 in Laravel

Tags: laravel, smtp, sendgrid

I am trying to switch from gmail smtp to sendgrid. And I am stuck on the error code "Address in mailbox given [apikey] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2."

MAIL_MAILER=smtp 
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net 
MAIL_PORT=25 
MAIL_USERNAME=apikey
MAIL_PASSWORD=My_Api_key
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Test"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=test@email.com

My mail.php

```php
return [

    'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),

    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],

        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],

        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],

        'postmark' => [
            'transport' => 'postmark',
        ],

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'transport' => 'log',
            'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
        ],

        'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],
    ],


    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'test@email.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Test'),
    ],

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 2822, 3.6.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2822#section-3.6.2) refers mainly to the address an email is sent from. In your example above you have `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` set to `test@email.com` which I presume is not an email address you own or have control over.

From the RFC:

> In all cases, the "From:" field SHOULD NOT contain any mailbox that does not belong to the author(s) of the message.

I would make sure you have either [verified your email address as single sender](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/sender-verification) or [performed domain authentication](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication) and then use that email address as your `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS`.

If you are still having trouble with this, can you share your `config/mail.php` file too.

Comment: I have added my mail.php to the main question, thank you for your help. Instead of test email I have real email which is verified on a sendgrid.

Comment: Have you edited your `.env` file and restarted your server? Have you tried entering the email you want to use directly into `mail.php` in place of `env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS')`?

Comment: Yes, I have edited, .env, cleared all cache. Also tried to use email directly in mail.php. Still the same error.

Comment: How are you sending the email? Could there be something wrong with the email address you are sending the mail to?

Comment: Scratch that, I looked around a bit more and it's to do with the From, Sender or Reply-To fields. Can you share the email address at all? Could it be an invalid email address?

Comment: It is the same email address I used with gmail smtp, 100% valid.

Comment: My understanding is that [Gmail doesn't use the `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` when you use it as an smtp transport](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46070359/28376). So perhaps it isn't valid but that wasn't an issue with Gmail?

Comment: No, everything worked well.

Comment: Can you share the email address with me over email? I’m at philnash@twilio.com.

Comment: Yes, I sent it to you.